# Does C++ constrain the period of std::rand?

Tags: c++, random, language-lawyer

Does the C++ standard place any constraints on the minimum / maximum period of the sequence returned by `std::rand`?

Comment: Its utterly underspecified. Afaik `rand() { return 42; }` would be conforming.

Comment: `std::rand` is a C runtime function from <cstdlib> aka <stdlib.h>. How is it relevant to C++ standard and [tag:language-lawyer]?

Comment: @273K -- it's part of the C++ language. Yes, many people don't like using the C standard library in C++, but that's a matter of taste, not specification.

Comment: This seems relevant - there are better alternatives available: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random

Comment: Since C++11 `std::rand` should be avoided. It is best to use own instance of `std::mt19937` it is fast it has really long period, has good other statistical properties and there will not be race conditions which are outside of your control.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### No.

28.5.10 says *"The rand and srand functions have the semantics specified in the C standard library."*

C17 standard only has this to say about `rand`:

> *The rand function computes a sequence of pseudo-random integers in the range 0 to RAND_MAX.*
> *The rand function is not required to avoid data races with other calls to pseudo-random sequence generation functions. The implementation shall behave as if no library function calls the rand function.*
> *The rand function returns a pseudo-random integer.*
> *The value of the RAND_MAX macro shall be at least 32767*

with a footnote

*"There are no guarantees as to the quality of the random sequence produced and some implementations are known to produce sequences with distressingly non-random low-order bits. Applications with particular requirements should use a generator that is known to be sufficient for their needs."*

No constraints on period, quality exist. A function returning 0 and 1 alternatively would be conforming to the standard.

Comment: @JerryCoffin technically, no. While it is obvious that the intention was to provide facility capable of that, it is not a requirement. Only requrement is that produced number was in specified range without exceeding it. (and you can replace 0 and 1 with 0 and 32767, this will not change the point).

Comment: Yep, the requirement is to not produce a number larger than `RAND_MAX`, there's no guarantee it'll produce every number between 0 and `RAND_MAX`

Comment: @JerryCoffin this is [tag:language-lawyer]. Things like _"expectations"_ or _"common sense"_ do not matter here. And I would not be so quick to say "this will never happen in real life", because implementation launching a game on encountering unknown pragma, just because it is legal, did happen. In GCC, no less.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot: One could argue that many such things will never happen in real life *when using compilers whose maintainers aren't being deliberately obtuse*.  I don't think the fact that some versions of gcc would launch rogue in response to unknown pragmas condradicts that statement.